# Архитектура пула ресурсов

Tags: java, многопоточность, потоки-данных, очередь

Задание:
Создать многопоточное приложение, корректно работающее с разделяемыми ресурсами и избегающее ситуаций взаимной блокировки. Любая сущность, желающая получить доступ к разделяемому ресурсу, должна быть потоком. Использовать java.util.concurrent и java.util.concurrent.locks.
Тема:
CallCenter. Имеется несколько операторов. Оператор может обслуживать одновременно одного клиента. При отсутствии свободных операторов CallCenter ставит звонки в очередь. Клиент, стоящий в очереди, может положить трубку и перезвонить ещё раз через некоторое время. Реализовать на Java.

Я выделил классы Client, Operator и CallCenter. Ясно, что должна быть очередь клиентов, очередь операторов, а CallCenter должен их обслуживать. Не очень ясно как всё устроить.

Вопрос: какие из этих классов должны быть потоками, какую очередь лучше использовать в моём случае?

Comment: Слово «должны быть» как-то лишнее. Вы можете обойтись и вовсе без потоков в этой задаче. Или с не привязанными к потокам задачами, наподобие горутин. Или с потоками. Всё зависит лишь от вашего выбора.

Comment: Кроме всего прочего, методы объекта могут _выполняться_ в отдельном потоке без того, чтобы сам класс _был_ потоком. Но это, наверное, придирка к терминологии.

Comment: Обязательно выполнить именно с потоками

Comment: А, это _учебное задание_? Тогда спросите у лектора, что ж вы у нас спрашиваете? Обязательно нужен поток — сделайте решение без потоков, последней командой запустите пустой поток, делов-то!

Comment: Да, учебное. Задание на курсах

Comment: Чувствую, что для данной задачи должен быть соответствующий паттерн. Но никакой конкретно в голову не приходит. Напишите, если кто знает...

Comment: Этот паттерн называется "пул ресурсов" :)

Comment: Точно! Спасибо! :)

Comment: @VladD Вижу, моя шутка про массив `dummy[42]` легко обобщается в паттерн и скоро станет трендом :)

Comment: @Shamov: Паттерн «ПреподОтвяжись»?

Comment: @VladD Или менее агрессивный вариант - «ЧитимБезПалева».

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если это учебное задание на пул ресурсов - то очевидно, что ресурсом тут будет оператор, ведь при попытке навечно запереть клиента в пуле он будет вырываться, кричать что хочет домой и пытаться позвонить в полицию.

А класс CallCenter тут явно лишний - ведь в задаче есть только клиенты и операторы, колл-центр не более чем антураж. Конечно, в решении понадобится какой-нибудь контейнер для операторов - но назвать его лучше как `OperatorsPool`, чтобы было понятно что он делает.

Методом исключений, роль потока остается клиенту. Звонок оператору - это вызов некоторого метода, получающего элемент из пула. Отмена звонка - это прерывание вызова, обычно такая операция делается через CancellationToken, но можно обойтись и тайм-аутом. Завершение звонка - это возврат оператора в пул.

Comment: Почему же `CallCenter` лишний? Это может быть завуалированное название собственно пула. Клиент дёргает пул-`CallCenter`, тот выдаёт ему оператора и ждёт, когда клиент оператора освободит, чтобы отдать его другому клиенту. Опционально можно отслеживать время, которое оператор тратит на клиента, и при превышении определённого порога насильственно отбирать оператора.

Comment: Потому что название `CallCenter` ни о чем не говорит - подобные классы имеют дурную привычку разрастаться до божественных объектов. Название `OperatorPool` в этом плане выглядит куда лучше.